# Как называется и как можно реализовать данный дизайн?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно создать "прилипание" каждого изображения в карте и написать адаптер с навигацией (точки для демонстрации общего количества картинок и та, на которой находится пользователь)

Comment: Можете посмотреть что-то из этого, как для начала. https://uxplanet.org/top-15-android-navigation-github-ui-libraries-and-components-java-kotlin-a90da35dead3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю Вам нужна вот эта билиотека [dotindicator](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator)